# Setting up Umbraco Indexes

Tags: umbraco, indexing, lucene

I've created a site using Umbraco 6.02, and I'm going over all the final configuration of the site now, and I've come to indexes. I've done some research, but I just cant find in simple terms what I need to include in each section and why.

Which fields I should include in the `<IndexUserFields>` section of the index? Is it just the fields I'll be using to search with, for example:`currentNode.Children(x => x.bodyText.Contains("*"))?` Or fields that I'll be using to sort nodes such as a `date field` for news articles? Or is there more to it than that?

Which document types do I need to put in the `<IncludeNodeTypes>` section and the `<ExcludeNodeTypes>` section and why?

And do I add my fields to one of the already created indexes, or do I create my own?

Answer (score 7):

Old post but may help someone along the way.

---

http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2011/9/16/examining-examine.aspx

You can create custom indexes (if you desire) to lock down what types of searching you're doing. Many times you have a search box somewhere on your page and you only want to search certain `doc types` and their related content.

Keep in mind that you can create NEW index sets, but remember that you'll need to register them in the `Config/ExamineSettings.config` file as well as the `Config/ExamineIndex.config` file.

The link above is how I got mine to work correctly for just searching (2) different doc types (which Examine uses as `NodeTypes`) in the config.

**The settings below were created using the already default `ExternalIndexer`, not a newly created custom one.**

---

The file that you want to edit is in `Config/ExamineIndex.config`. The set that you want to edit is the `ExternalIndexSet` (by default). The path will point to the `external` temp folder

```
  <IndexSet SetName="ExternalIndexSet" IndexPath="~/App_Data/TEMP/ExamineIndexes/External/">
```

For fields, that goes in the `IndexUserFields` section, which are custom properties that you have defined on your doc types

```
<IndexUserFields>
  <add Name="itemNumber" />    <-- custom property
  <add Name="productName" />   <-- custom property
</IndexUserFields>
```

The `doc types` (NodeTypes) that you want are whatever you named your document types. Remember that these are the alias, not the name

```
<IncludeNodeTypes>
  <add Name="Product" />  <-- document type
  <add Name="Variant" />  <-- document type
</IncludeNodeTypes>
```

Remember after setting this up you want to re-index your Examine. You can get to this by logging into the backend of Umbraco and going to `Developer`, then clicking on the tab that says `Examine Management`.

Please note that the interface is `Umbraco 7` but the config file will still be applicable for `v6`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a nice concise guide - been looking for ages!

Comment: It did help! Thanks.